# EventHandler always null in .dll, subscribed from another class

Tags: c#, class, events, dll, .net-4.5

The situation: I wrote a TCP/IP library for myself. It's a set of client.cs and server.cs in a .dll file. Now, I have a test program (client and server) in the same solution. The connection is fine, I can send and receive message both side, with multiple clients too. My pain is that I want to create an `event`; I read the MSDN How-To, I followed the delegate method, but when I raise the event (after I subscribed to it), it's always null. :(

Here are the simplified code:

**Server.cs**

```
public class ClientConnectedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string Clname = "";
    public ClientConnectedEventArgs(string clientname)
    {
        Clname = clientname;
    }

    public string ClientName
    {
        get { return Clname; }
        set { Clname = value; }
    }
}

public delegate void ClientConnectedEventHandler(object sender, ClientConnectedEventArgs e);

public class Server
{
    public event ClientConnectedEventHandler ClientConnected;

    protected virtual void OnClientConnected(ClientConnectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var temp = ClientConnected;
        if (temp != null) temp(this, e);
    }

    internal class clientService : Server
    {
        internal int ConnectClient(TcpClient newclient)
        {
            clname = ReceiveStringFrom();
            OnClientConnected(new ClientConnectedEventArgs(clname));
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs** (Server Test Console Application)

```
class Program
{
    static UniTcpIP.Server srv;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        srv = new UniTcpIP.Server();
        srv.ClientConnected += new UniTcpIP.ClientConnectedEventHandler(srv_ClientConnected);
        if (srv.Start("127.0.0.1", 6969) == 0) Console.WriteLine("Server started");
    }

    static void srv_ClientConnected(object sender, UniTcpIP.ClientConnectedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED: " + e.ClientName);
    }
}
```

My goal is to create an Event (ClientConnected) which is fired when a client connects. I don't know why, this eventhandler is always null. I read 2 pages of google results, but none of them helped.

*Some debug info:*
When I insert a breakpoint after subscription then the `srv.ClientConnected` value is: `{Method = {Void srv_ClientConnected(System.Object, UniTcpIP.ClientConnectedEventArgs)}}`
But then, when the event is raised, it's null in the **Server.cs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a good, [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's impossible to know for sure what the issue is. However, based on what you've posted here, it appears to me that the `ConnectClient()` method being called belongs to a different instance (and indeed, a completely different *type*) than the one you used earlier to subscribe to the event.

Your program creates an instance of `Server` and then subscribes to that instance's `ClientConnected` event. You don't show the call to `ConnectClient()`, but I see no evidence any such method even exists in the `Server` class. It's only in the `clientService` class. You also don't show any instance of that class, but it for sure cannot be the instance of `Server` you subscribe to in the code you did show.

So if you are in fact calling `ConnectClient()` on an instance of `clientService`, then that is a completely different instance from the `Server` object whose event you did subscribe to. And since no code subscribed to the `clientService` instance's event, the event field is of course still set to `null`.

Again, without a good code example, it's impossible to know for sure what the best way to fix this is. But it seems likely that you need to make two changes:

1. Pull `clientService` out from inside the `Server` class, and just make it a top-evel class that inherits `Server`. (At the same time, consider renaming the type so that it uses Pascal case instead of camel-case, per normal .NET convention…i.e. call it `ClientService`).
2. Instead of creating an instance of `Server` in your `Main()` method, create an instance of `clientService`.

You'll also need to make changes to remove the usages of whatever instance of `clientService` you *did* have elsewhere in your code, but I can't comment on that because you didn't include that in your code example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can't test it right now, but one more thing that came in my mind. The whole clientService thing is running on a different Thread. Does it matter? Sorry for my stupidness, I never wrote event handling, and I think tcp/ip is not a simple beginning

Comment: That it runs in a different thread certainly could "matter", but it won't affect the basic usage of the event.

Comment: All right, I did your instructions, but they aren't working. However, I made the event static

Comment: So, I followed your instructions, but none of them helped. :( Now, I made the event static, and it works. Any idea, what am i doing wrong? Anyway, have my upvote, for your help :)

Comment: As I mentioned, it's impossible to know for sure what's wrong, without a complete code example. See [mcve]. Assuming you have the correct instance of `Server` when you subscribe to the event (i.e. the instance that will _raise_ the event), then the subscribed handler will be present in the field when you raise the event. But there's not enough code in your question for me to know which instance is being used to raise the event, nor even how the event is raised (i.e. there's no call to `ConnectClient()`. If you'd like to improve the question, I'm always happy to take another look.